# False after casting interned strings to objects

Tags: c#, string

I was trying to better understand string's interning in c# and got into the following situation:

```
string a ="Hello";
string b ="Hello";
string c = new string(new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o'});
string d = String.Intern(c);
Console.WriteLine(a==b);
Console.WriteLine(c==d);
Console.WriteLine((object)a==(object)b);
Console.WriteLine((object)c==(object)d);
```

I'm getting the following result in console:

> True
>   True
>   True
>   False

The mistake for me is that why is the 4th false ?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((object)c==(object)d);` => here `==` checks for reference equality. Use `(object)c.Equals((object)d);` and see if it returns `True`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: While that is in a sense correct, I think the OP is aware of that. (These sort of edge cases epitomise my reasons for preferring good old `std::string` from C++.)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes, that return true. But `==` in case of objects also checks the references. And I don't understand why it returns `false`.

Comment: It's explained in the documentation of `String.Intern`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right, OP may aware of the `Equals` method here. But `String.Intern` itself retrieves system reference to specified string, which depends on how intern pool works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had not created `a` (and `b`), then `Console.WriteLine((object)c==(object)d);` would have resulted in `True`.

However, at the time that you do `string d = String.Intern(c);` the string `"Hello"` already exists in the string intern pool, due to `a`, so the call to intern `c` finds the already existing `"Hello"` and returns it.

So, if `"Hello"` had not already been interned, then the `"Hello"` of `c` would have been interned, in which case the returned `d` would have been equal to `c`.

Proof: if you do `Console.WriteLine(b==d); it should return`True`.  (I bet it will.)

Comment: Even if I remove `a` and `b` anyway `Console.WriteLine((object)c==(object)d);` returns `False`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov b==d returns true but the reason must be different than you described because if I change a="Hello1" and b="Hello1" then c==d still returns false

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov - I ran the code and removed `a` & `b` and it returned `True` for me.

Comment: @MistyK I wonder why `Console.WriteLine(c==d);` returns `True` and `Console.WriteLine((object)c==(object)d);` and returns False, while `==` is checking references and if they were equal before casting why they got different and why the same is not beeing in case with `a` and `b`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov If I remove `a` and `b`, it returns `True`. I bet you should have the same result base on my understanding of intern and inter pool.

Comment: @Enigmativity https://dotnetfiddle.net/0UM6tQ look results second line  `False`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov the difference is that c==d will use string overload to compare strings (it's normal string comparison) and (object)c == (object)d will use reference comparison always. I can't edit the previous post but I meant (object)c == (object)d returns false

Comment: @MistyK ok, take look at this https://dotnetfiddle.net/0UM6tQ

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov - That's not how it runs when I do it locally.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov yep, everything as expected and the same question remains - why doesn't String.Intern use the same reference here? I don't know the answer here. It just proves that Mike's explanation isn't valid.

Comment: @MistyK I am a little confused with this `True`,`False`s now. I have locally run this same code and got 4 `True` as a result

Comment: @MistyK http://take.ms/hoK81

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the method return

> The system's reference to str, if it is interned; otherwise, a new reference to a string with the value of str.

and in the remarks:

> if you assign the same literal string to several variables, the runtime retrieves the same reference to the literal string from the intern pool and assigns it to each variable.

Apparently creating the string `"Hello"` out of a char array results not in the *same literal string*, and it seems not to end up in the pool. changing the c-line to `string c = "Hello"` results in the output of `True`

Comment: No wonder that changing c ="Hello" will output true. String will be interned by CLR. The question is why manual intern is different than CLR intern?

Comment: @MistyK - Why do you think it is different? It seems consistent to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity if you have two strings - a="Hello" and b="Hello" which are compile time constant then they will be both pointing to the same instance. However if you have a=new string(new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o'}) and if you intern it like this: string b = String.Intern(a) they don't point to the same instance.

Comment: @MistyK - They can't because it would break the run-time. The constructed string is on the heap and can't be moved otherwise the reference to an existing string would be moved. The interned string can be moved - and it must be to become interned. So you've got one reference that can't move and one that must. They both then can't be the same reference.

Comment: @Enigmativity yup, you are right. I think Peter Duniho explained it pretty well in the comment.